# How can you replace Redux by the react ContextAPI in a Django App

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, react-context

I recently learned how to mimic the redux behavior with the use of createContext(). I know how to use the react contextAPI and react hooks. But now, I try to connect both django and react, but every tutorials are mentioning Redux. How can I replace Redux by createContext + react hooks ?

Comment: Can you provide some code examples of what you've tried?

Comment: @iofjuupasli sorry, it was an open question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `createContext` and `useReducer` like this:

```
const StoreContext = React.createContext();

const App = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      <Content />
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Inside your components you could then use `useContext(StoreContext)` to get access to your `state` and `dispatch`.

Comment: Thank you ! I have to try this. I will tell you if I’m a bit lost with this method